# Can't dismiss AVPlayerViewController in iOS16

Tags: avplayerviewcontroller, ios16

Since iOS 16 made changes to AVPlayerViewController, the dismiss button ('x') in the top left corner simply doesn't work. The 'tap' is normal, but it feels like the UIButton target doesn't do anything. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Is there a delegate method or setting that needs to be used for it to work? It all worked perfectly before iOS 16. Implementation below:

```
AVPlayerViewController *vc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
vc.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoInfo.VideoURL]];
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using animation. It can be fixed but I don't know why.

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I tried that, but I couldn't get it to work properly until I embedded the AVPlayerViewController as a child view controller inside a regular UIViewController. Then it seemed to work as intended. Thanks for the suggestion.